# Positioning content components on a home page pattern

Tags: reactjs, react-native, design-patterns, frontend

I want to find a way to be able to change my home page sections on my react-native mobile using a back-office/api.

My home page has several different sections: banner, carousel, products, users. And I want to be able to re-order then and change for example the banner.

My first guess is to store the placement in my database, fetch it and parse it to place the elements according what I set as data in my database.

But I wanted to know if someone knows a pattern to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

In your React Native app, use the fetch or axios library to retrieve the placement and content information from your back-office/API.